# Bakta for annotating multiple genomes

Tags: annotations

I need to annotate 500 genomes with Bakta, which are located in the folder 'genomes.' Additionally, I need to run it in the background, measure the execution time, and save all outputs in the same folder 'rest_bakta.' I tried using a 'for' loop, but it only iterates over the first file and not the others. If anyone can guide me on how to modify the script, I would greatly appreciate it.
Here's the command I used:

```
nohup bash -c 'time for file in genomes/*.fna; do bakta --db /bakta_db/db/ --output rest_bakta/ --prefix $(basename $file .fna) -- genus STAPHYLOCOCCUS --threads 20 $file; done' > output_bakta.txt 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: Try to ask here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have the same issue of only iterating over the first file. What was your solution?